# Unable to create a custom domain in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-route53

I have completed my user pool configuration in the AWS Cognito and I got a cognito URL like the below which I'm trying to replace with a custom domain:-

https://XXXXXXXX.auth.ap-southeast-1.amazoncognito.com
But getting an error:-

```
`[InvalidParameterException] Failed to create custom domain "oauth.XXXXXXXXX.com".

requestId: 22309494-1b97-456a-baea-f77ae29470f1 time: Sat Aug 12 2023 21:03:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) code: InvalidParameterException message: Custom domain is not a valid subdomain: Was not able to resolve the root domain, please ensure an A record exists for the root domain.`
```

[image]

I have a public hosted zone like **example.com** that has got NS records of the subdomain, **oauth.example.com**(created as a separate hosted zone). Now, I'm not sure which A record inside example.com I should point to. Also, does Cognito creates any CloudFront distribution endpoint by itself when we set up Cognito? I do not see any distribution endpoint that I should point this A record to?

Answer (score 0):

You should create **CNAME record** in side **route53**.
**CNAME** should point to alias target that could be found inside
**user pool -> app integration**
(like on image below) [image]